# Showing Word documenet & PowerPoint 2010 inside sharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have uploaded a word document `.docx` to my document library inside SharePoint server 2013. but when i click on the document from the document library i will get "The webpage cannot be displayed" on the browser. while if i select to download a copy of the file it will work well? any idea what is wrong ? or why the browser will not prompt the user to download the file instead of displayed The webpage cannot be displayed ??

I have also chnage the Web Application "Browse File handler" from Strict to Permissive , but still the problem exsists.

**Edit**

I have noted something new, that when using Safari 5.1.7 it will automatically prompted the user to either open or save the document. while on IE & firefox it will show the following error on the browser "The webpage cannot be displayed"

Comment: It might be trying to open in Office Web Applications which might not be properly configured? What are the settings in the document library Advanced Settings when it comes to "Opening Documents in the Browser".

Comment: Are you using Office Web Apps?

Comment: the document library advance setting regarding the "opening Documents in the browser" is "Use the server default (Open in the browser) ". and i am not using Office Web Apps, rather i am using document library App ?? any advice